# Resizing custom UINavigationController's titleView

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

Having some trouble with a custom UINavigationController.

I'm trying to use a new typeface for my app, and I'm finding that the typeface slightly exceeds the bounds of some of my UIViews, most notably my UINavigationController's title (note the 'C' at the end of the title, which is clipped in the top-right).

[image: The 'C' at the end of the title is clipped slightly]

In my current implementation, I have a custom UINavigationController subclass which, in the awakeFromNib method, sets the tint and font of the NavigationBar. My two attempts at a solution include: setting self.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = NO; and trying to resize the bar's titleView, although this view appears inaccessible from within the custom UINavigationController. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

UILabel has a problem with italic text. Set the frame of that UILabel to be the CGRect from sizeToFit but a little bit wider.